# How to use ES6 modules in node.js?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

There is something I fail to understand with ES6 modules in the context of node.js.

Let's say I have this simple node app. It is based on an iisnode example but I added an `import` at the top.

hello.js:

```
import mod1 from './module1';

var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(mod1.data);
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

This will result in `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

However if I **rename hello.js to hello.mjs** I get the following error: `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\hellomodules\hello.mjs`

Seems like a catch to me, what is the way out?

(iisnode version is 0.2.26, node version is v13.8.0)

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/17063#issuecomment-344782748

Comment: @Hogan, I do not see how that applies in my case. The issue you linked to was a case of misleadingly worded error message which was fixed way back then. Furthermore, std/esm or esm should not be needed at all since nodejs 12.

Comment: ok -- it is the same error message you posted.

Answer (score 3):

Solving this issue:

1. If the file format is `.js`, or if the Node version < 13, add `"type": "module"` in **package.json**
2. To allow debug, add `"runtimeArgs": ["--experimental-modules"]` in **.vscode/launch.json**
3. Always use the flag `--experimental-modules` to run: `node --experimental-modules hello.mjs`

In the newer Node versions it isn't necessary to take these steps